# How to show Amazon seller's products in my Magento website?

Tags: magento-1

How do I export all of my products (including FBA products) from my Amazon seller account and import them to my Magento community store.

Answer (score 1):

There is some extensions available for importing products from amazon to magento.
http://magegaga.com/amazon2magento.html this non free version of extension is for importing products from Amazon to your Magento store.